# Использование "android::java" + "C++" в одном приложении

Tags: android, java, c++

В общем сейчас у меня есть "учебное" задание: реализовать инженерный калькулятор на С++

---

---

Я могу сделать в виде класса "`calc`" который

1. принимает `std::string`
2. обрабатывает исключения (не
       выбрасывая их наружу) которые можно
       получить через `get_error();` (при
       желании)
3. сам парсит строку в дерево и считает
       её

и соответственно могу сделать обёртку-интерфейс в `C++ Builder`

обёртка будет делать:

1. формировать строку `std::string` или
       `std::char*`
2. передавать строку в "`calc`"
3. спрашивать у "`calc`" есть ли ошибки?
4. брать из "`calc`" объект "`error`" в
       котором хранится: текст_ошибки +
       позиция_в_строке
5. получать результат решения

---

---

**что хочу узнать:**

1. насколько геморойно будет создание
       обёртки-интерфейса в `android::java` и
       прикручивании моего класса "`calc`" ?
2. будет ли гемор с зависимостью от
       `hardware` ?
3. подводные камни ?

**p.s.** стою перед выбором, потому и спрашиваю

- написать всё это на `С++` (сейчас и     качественно)
- или на `java` (через год когда овладею  `java`, а сейчас набросать велосипед,  чисто под оценку...)

Comment: Я бы лично выбрал вариант 1 - полностью это написать на с++. Благо, это андроид сдк позволяет.

Comment: а я бы на джаве =) там возле часа работы

Comment: Я так и не понял суть вопроса (наверное туповат) - чел хочет написать калькулятор для Android'а или как?

Comment: @Barmaley я интересуюсь насколько геморройный использовать С++ в андройде, а калькулятор это описание  задачи

Comment: Насколько я знаю Android не дружит с С++ Builder'ом (могу ошибаться). Рекомендованная среда Eclipse (в случае виндов с CygWin > 1.7). Посмотрите мануалы к [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

Comment: @Barmaley ты неверно понял... я могу сейчас реализовать на С++ (VS,GCC...)  класс "calc" для консоли. И сделать gui-интерфейс в билдере...  

так вот я могу это сделать на хорошо и в дальнейшем использовать в java, или хреново и потом заново написать уже полностью на java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если писать все на Java то это будет намного проще и быстрее, но и вполне возможно (и не очень сложно) скомпилировать код написан в C++ на Android с помощью Android NDK. Вот хороший [туториал](http://idev.by/android/21115/).

Если если будешь использовать Android NDK то тебе по любому придется иметь дело с Java  и Android SDK, но есть способ написать приложение в C++ без использования Java вот [ссылка](http://jia3ep.blogspot.pt/2012/01/c-android-4-java.html).

Answer (score 1):

> > насколько геморойно будет создание обёртки-интерфейса в android::java и прикручивании моего класса "calc" ?

Если знаете, как делать, то не очень то и сложно.

> > будет ли гемор с зависимостью от hardware ?

конечно. Под каждую платформу нужно будет собрать отдельную so. Хотя в Вашем случае все ограничиться просто добавлением пары строк в android.mk

> > подводные камни ?
> > например - отладка.
> >
> > или на java(через год когда овладею java, а сейчас набросать велосипед, чисто под оценку...)

в данном случае жава не настолько сложна. Если классы написаны красиво, то спортировать будет легко (поубирать деструкторы, заменить std::string на String).

Но не ведомо, какого размера там калькулятор. Может там с такими рассчетами...

P.S. Java все равно придется учится - прослойку писать.

Comment: вот насчёт расчётов да... 

планируется добавление +100500 функций (ну это как всегда... :)) ) 

если конкретно то мысль: написать полноценный расширяемый калькулятор с парочкой изюминок, который пойдёт в портфолио и будет дипломным проектом...  

по сложности вычислений должен как минимум считать "(16^23)*mod(33)"
и что то типа [вот этого][1]


  [1]: http://lib3.podelise.ru/tw_files2/urls_12/14/d-13654/7z-docs/6_html_1bcb9dc3.gif

Comment: тогда для начала напишите на джава, хотя бы с минимальными функциями. А там будет видно.